# Java HashTable: What is the most elegant way to clone hashtable on defined interval on inverse order?

Tags: java, hashtable

What is the most elegant way to copy keys and values from one hashtable to another between start and end keys in inverse order? For example original hashtable is:

```
[<1,"object1">; <2, "object2">; <4,"object3">; <5,"object4">;<7,"object5">;<8,"object6">]
```

after calling function getPartListOfNews(2,4) it should return hashtable like this:

```
[<7,"object5">;<5,"object4">;<4,"object3">]
```

I had made code to do it and it comes below, but I don't think is this a better way to do what i had described before. Is there ara any better solutions? How can I simplify this code?

```
public Hashtable<Integer, News> getPartListOfNews(int start, int end){
        Hashtable <Integer, News> tempNewsList = new Hashtable <Integer, News>();
        int total_to_get = end-start;
        int list_size = newsList.size();
        Object[] key_array = new Object[list_size];
        if(list_size < total_to_get){
            return newsList;
        }
        else{
            Enumeration e = newsList.keys();
            int index=0;
            while(e.hasMoreElements()){
                key_array[index] = e.nextElement();
                index  ;
            }
            for (int i=end; i>start; i--){
                tempNewsList.put((Integer)key_array[i], newsList.get(key_array[i]));
            }
            return tempNewsList;
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

```
public Hashtable<Integer, News> newsList = new Hashtable<Integer, News>();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to clone a HashTable in reverse order?

Comment: I'm making rss news reader for Android and this is serverside code. Hashtable is the cached news. Because of great amount of news I want to pass to Android only news between defined interval and news list should start from most recent news

Comment: Did nobody tell you that HashTables don't have ordering by key?

Comment: why to you need the integers? put it in a common list (e.g. a ArrayList) and call sublist(a, b) on it

Comment: HashTables was in project before. To change HashTables to ArrayList will take some time and I'm not sure that all things will will work well with ArrayLists

Comment: I had changed from HashTable to ArrayList... looks like working well for now. Thx for suggestion

Comment: The question is strictly meaningless. HashTables don't have orders, let alone reverse orders.

Comment: @Andriy: why did you delete your [JSoup question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915243/jsoup-dont-parse-div/7917791) without commenting on my answer? Why did I waste my time trying to help you? `DoNotHelpList.add(Andriy);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use a `LinkedHashMap` in your `newsList` attribute, to preserve insertion order. Also, it's better if you declare attributes and return values of methods using the `Map` interface instead of the concrete class used, in this way you can easily change the implementation, like this:

```
private Map<Integer, News> newsList = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, News>();
```

With the above in mind, here's my shot at solving your problem:

```
public Map<Integer, News> getPartListOfNews(int start, int end) {

    // first, get the range of keys from the original map

    List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (Integer key : newsList.keySet()) // iterates in insertion order
        keys.add(key);
    List<Integer> subkeys = keys.subList(start, end);

    // now add them in the required order

    Map<Integer, News> tempNewsList = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, News>();
    ListIterator<Integer> iter = subkeys.listIterator();
    while (iter.hasPrevious()) {
        Integer key = iter.previous();
        tempNewsList.put(key, newsList.get(key));
    }

    return tempNewsList;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your code does not have any effect. Hash table "breaks" the order. The order of elements in hash table depends on the particular hash implementation.

There are 2 types of Maps in JDK: HashMap and SortedMap (typically we use its implementation TreeMap). BTW do not use Hashtable: this is old, synchronized and almost obsolete implementation).

When you are using HashMap (and Hashtable) the order of keys is unpredictable: it depends on implementation of `hashCode()` method of class you are using as keys of your map. If you are using TreeMap you can use Comparator to change this logic.

If you wish your keys to be extracted in the same order you put them use `LinkedHashMap`.

Answer (score 1):

I think a HashTable is not ordered. If you use a ordered data structure (such as LinkedHashMap) you could sort it (with java build-in methods) and make a sublist. this should be 2 lines of code and very efficiant.